# Quick PHP echo help

Tags: php, wordpress

What is wrong with this?

```
echo '<a title="Last Chance" href="'.the_permalink().'" class="status open">Last Chance</a>';
```

As it's putting the `the_permalink()` before the `<a` instead of inside it.

Comment: What is `the_permalink()`? A url?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wordpress often `echo`'s the content out of the function instead of returning it.

Use `get_permalink()` instead.

```
echo '<a title="Last Chance" href="'.get_permalink().'" class="status open">Last Chance</a>';
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: General rule is that WP functions which produce output will echo directly. The `get_...` versions will return the same data instead of echoing.

Comment: I had to wait until today to choose your answer though :/

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks good to me (but see my edit comment).

Better is to embed PHP into HTML:

```
<a title="Last Chance" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="status open">
   Last Chance
</a>
```

*Edit: [As @Marwelln found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059111/quick-php-echo-help/5059144#5059144), `the_permalink()` is already echoing data. Still, this is a better solution than echoing the HTML.*

Comment: Yeah, the WordPress theme functions are *useful* like that :P

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have `echo "abc"` in the `the_permalink` function. In order for this to work as you wish, you have to `return "abc"` instead of using `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this (not inside echo )

```
<a title="Last Chance" href=" <?php the_permalink() ?> " class="status open">Last Chance</a>
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink for more details.